# Heteroscedasticity filter for time series

Tags: r, heteroscedasticity, filter

I am looking for a method or package in R that can remove heteroscedasticity from time series. Specifically, I have a number of time series to which I want to fit a VAR model. Each time series may or may not be heteroscedastic.

Comment: Your distinction seems spurious. In order to remove heteroscedasticity, you first need a model within which variance structure is one of several details. It's like saying "I want to remove trend, but I am not interested in modelling it." But there isn't a way of getting at trend that is universal and model-free; every method of defining trend makes at least tacit assumptions. Same with heteroscedasticity. A side note is that the notation here is over the top: all you need say is that you have several time series.

Comment: I'll edit the question to address your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical technique to suppress heteroscedasticity is [Box-Cox transform](http://onlinestatbook.com/2/transformations/box-cox.html)

I personally find it as a crude tool, and rarely use. I prefer stochastic approaches such as [GARCH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_conditional_heteroskedasticity#GARCH), which work better in my domain. Unlike, Box-Cox transform GARCH directly models varying volatility.

Another approach is log-transform. It's a special case of Box-Cox transform, but it works well when underlying series exhibit exponential growth, and the rate of growth has a constant volatility. In this case the levels have higher volatility at higher values. This works very well for certain kinds of unstable series, such as prices.